Can Higher moments be dominated by truncated variable?
Let X be a real-value variable such that $\mathbb{E}(X)=0$,$Var(X)=1$. Fix $u > 0$, denote $\widetilde{X}=X\mathbb{I}_{|X|>u}-m(u)$, where $m(u)=\mathbb{E}(X\mathbb{I}_{|X|>u})$. We can compute that $\mathbb{E}(\widetilde{X})=0$ and $Var(\widetilde{X})=1-(\sigma(u))^{2}-2(m(u))^{2} \leq 1$ where $(\sigma(u))^{2}=\mathbb{E}(X^{2}\mathbb{I}_{|X| \leq u})-(m(u))^{2}$. Obviously we have $m(u) \rightarrow 0, \sigma(u) \rightarrow 1$ as $u \rightarrow \infty$. I wonder if there exists a $r > 0$, such that $\mathbb{E}(|\widetilde{X}^{2}|^{1+\frac{1}{r}}) < \infty$.

Am I reading the problem correctly that it is sufficient to deal only with a single $X$ rather than an iid sequence $(X_k)$?

Oh yes, you are right.

I will edit the question for convenience

If I've understood your question correctly, I don't think so. Let $X$ be a random variable satisfying
$$\mathbb{P}( X \in \mathrm{d}x) = C_a \frac{1}{ |ax|^3 \log(1+|ax|)^2 } \mathrm{d}x,$$ where $C_a$ is a constant making it a pdf, and $a$ is chosen that the variable has unit variance. Then $X$ is symmetric, so in your case, $m(u) = 0$ for all $u$.
However, the tails have the property that $\mathbb{E}[|X|^{2+\varepsilon}] = \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[|\tilde{X}|^{2 + \varepsilon} ] = \infty$, regardless of the choice of $u$.
In fact, I think if you find any random variable $X$ satisfying $\mathbb{E}[|X|^2] = 1$ but $\mathbb{E}[|X|^{2+\varepsilon}]= \infty$, it will also serve as a counterexample, no matter the truncation.

Thank you, I get it.

No problem, Defender!
